# Iframe without border and scroll in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a requirement to display a iframe in new popup window such that the iFrame should look like a normal content of the child page instead of iframe.
Here is the code I am using.

```
<html>
.
.
<a class="link" href="javascript:popup();">show popup</a>
.
.
</html>
```

By Clicking the show popup, I am calling the javascript function there I am doing the window open.
code is:

```
window.open('../jsp/popupPage.jsp','targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1050,height=2000
```

And popupPage.jsp Contains the following content:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cancellation Policy</title>
</head>
<body>

<span>Blah Blah</span>
<br /><br />
<iframe src="http://google.co.in" ></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is iframe is displaying with border and scroll it doesn't looks good.
I want something like iframe content should look like a content of normal page along with Blah Blah
(iframe content)

I have used seamless property of HTML5 but that works only with chrome browser.
And one more point to note here is I can't use overflow="no" as I am not sure about the width and height of the iframe page coming from 3rd site.

Comment: also can add `seamless` to your iframe tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following tag when you declare your iframe.

```
 frameBorder="0"
```

Your tag would look like this

```
<iframe  frameBorder="0" src="http://google.co.in" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS to get rid of the borders:

```
iframe {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want to spread the iframe's dimensions, you would have to read the document dimensions inside the iframe and pass them to the parent document. This can be achieved by `postMessage()` function.
Add this javascript to the popupPage.jsp

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        window.parent.postMessage(document.body.clientWidth + ";" + document.body.clientHeight);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Then, in your `popup()` function, right before `window.open` you should add this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'); //or whatever your iframe is called
    var dimensions = e.data.split(";");
    iframe.width = dimensions[0];
    iframe.height = dimensions[1];
}, false);
```

To learn more about `postMessage` and `message` event read **[this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)**.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the frameBorder and  scrolling,

```
<iframe src="URL" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0">Browser not supported</iframe>
```

More about Frames and Styling, you can visit: http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/iframes-and-css.htm